# Aws dynamodb Error Error [UnknownError]: Not Found (aws-sdk)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to **add elements** in a **table in dynamodb** like in the example below but when I run it I get this error message:

```
Error Error [UnknownError]: Not Found
    at Request.extractError (C:\Users\caval\Documents\GitRepos\express-es6-rest-api\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:51:27)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\caval\Documents\GitRepos\express-es6-rest-api\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\caval\Documents\GitRepos\express-es6-rest-api\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\caval\Documents\GitRepos\express-es6-rest-api\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (C:\Users\caval\Documents\GitRepos\express-es6-rest-api\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\caval\Documents\GitRepos\express-es6-rest-api\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at C:\Users\caval\Documents\GitRepos\express-es6-rest-api\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\caval\Documents\GitRepos\express-es6-rest-api\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\caval\Documents\GitRepos\express-es6-rest-api\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\caval\Documents\GitRepos\express-es6-rest-api\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  message: 'Not Found',
  code: 'UnknownError',
  statusCode: 404,
  time: 2020-07-05T08:21:43.936Z,
  requestId: undefined,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 38.04958058577693
}
```

I **tried** also with **getItems**, **delteItems**... and I get the **same error**. Removing it I don't get any error, so the error come from these methods for sure.

```
   let ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
      apiVersion: "2012-08-10",
      endpoint: "http://localhost:8080",
      region: "eu-west-1",
      accessKeyId: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
    });

    let params = {
      TableName: "namOfTheTable",
      Item: {
        uuid: { N: "123" },
        name: { S: JSON.stringify(req.query.mod) },
      },
    };

    const addMod = ddb.putItem(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
      } else {
        console.log("Success", data);
      }
    });
```

**Edit:** the problem was that I was not using the local version so I needed to remove the property `endpoint`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 404 not found error is being returned from `http://localhost:8080`.

Are you sure that DynamoDB local is running, and if so have you set it to run on port `8080`?

By default DynamoDB local runs on port `8000` according to the documentation on [local DynamoDB usage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes.html).

**Additional Note**

After discussing with OP, DynamoDB local was not setup on their host machine which is what caused the 404 issues.

Comment: tha fact is that I did not download dynamodb locally, I was trying to use it without downloading it

Comment: I mean I'm creating some api so  the localhost:8000 should be just about the api not dynamodb

Comment: The localhost is for a local DynamoDB though, this is running a database locally on your host machine :)

Comment: mmm  but aws-sdk shoud not just connect me to the aws db?

Comment: If you don't want to run it locally then you would instead connect using an IAM key, IAM secret and a DynamoDB name from within the AWS system (retrievable via console or CLI).

Comment: sorry for the stupid question. with aws-sdk am I running it locally automatically or i need to download it?

Comment: Its fine, it can be rather confusing :). If you run the aws-sdk and you want to use local dynamodb you will need to download it locally and run on your host. If you want to just interact with a DynamoDB table you've created in AWS you do not need to download the dynamodb-local. Alternatively if you run docker you can run via that too: https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/ :)

Comment: i just want to create/delete.... tables in dynamodb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217241/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-gianmarco).

Comment: Have updated answer to state the root cause behind this error